# Google Apps Marketplace Scopes Not All Authorising

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace

The Google Apps Script Webapp I want to deploy in the marketplace has all scopes set in the SDK, and asks permissions for all of them. After initially granting them, it seems like 2 scopes did not authorise. This causes the review process to fail.

Scopes configured:

[image: Scopes in Marketplace SDK]

Scopes that were still needed:

[image: Scopes that were still needed after opening the app]

I have no clue now actually?

Comment: Ever figure out a solution to this?